# Updated data on Parse Cloud is not Loading

Tags: android, parse-platform

I have created a comment class where the users can comment their opinions. But when I send write the new comment is does not refresh the comment I have to restart the activity for the comments to load. I don't understand how can that be achieved. Tried referring to a lot of tutorials online but I couldn't find a solution to that.

I call this RemoteDataTask Method in my onCreate

```
  private class RemoteDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            parseCommentsList = new ArrayList<>();
            try {
                ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<>(
                        "Comments");
                query.whereEqualTo("videoId", videoID);
                query.setCachePolicy(ParseQuery.CachePolicy.NETWORK_ELSE_CACHE);
                query.orderByDescending("createdAt");
                ob = query.find();
                for (ParseObject country : ob) {
                    ParseComments map = new ParseComments();
                    ParseFile dp = (ParseFile)country.get("profilepictures");
                    String comments = country.getString("Comment");
                    String commentUser = country.getString("senderName");
                    map.setComments(comments);
                    map.setProfileName(commentUser);
                    map.setProfilePic(dp.getUrl());
                    parseCommentsList.add(map);
                }
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.comments_list);
            adapter = new CommentsAdapter(SingleVideoView.this,
                    parseCommentsList);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
```

Here is the Adapter for the comments

```
public class CommentsAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    // Declare Variables
    Context context;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    private List<ParseComments> parseCommentsList = null;
    private ArrayList<ParseComments> arraylist;

    public CommentsAdapter(Context context,
                           List<ParseComments> parseCommentsList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.parseCommentsList = parseCommentsList;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.arraylist = new ArrayList<ParseComments>();
        this.arraylist.addAll(parseCommentsList);
    }

    public class ViewHolder {
        TextView comment;
        TextView name;
        ImageView profilePic;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return parseCommentsList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return parseCommentsList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder holder;
        if (view == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.comments_layout, null);
            // Locate the TextViews in listview_item.xml
            holder.comment = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.comments);
            holder.name = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.name);
            holder.profilePic = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.profilePic);
            view.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }
        // Set the results into TextViews
        holder.comment.setText(parseCommentsList.get(position).getComments());
        holder.name.setText(String.valueOf(parseCommentsList.get(position).getProfileName()));
        Picasso.with(context)
                .load(parseCommentsList.get(position).getProfilePic())
                .transform(new CircleTransform())
                .resize(70,70)
                .into(holder.profilePic);
        return view;
    }
}
```

Comment: The old comments load but the new comment which I create does not load seamlessly I have to restart the activity to load new sent comment.

Comment: at a time you do to adapter notifyDataSetChanged(); when user can do comment ??

Comment: @HardikParmar I used loadobjects() with Runnable so its loading now

Comment: But this is one type of thread bro.